# Asp.net MVC 4 getJson work for create but not for edit. Seems to have an odd url in edit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm writing a MVC 4 app, I have a javascript function to support a couple of cascading dropdowns. The javascript is in a js file and I'm trying to use it for both create and edit view.  It works great for the create view, but doesn't work from my edit view.  I've looked at the network traffic using IE's developer tools, and notice the url from the create call is correct, Controller/MyActionMethod.  The url from the edit call is controller/edit/controller/MyActionMethod.

I currently am using the default route config, it's seems to have worked fine, so I haven't delved into it too deeply.

Any thoughts on why controller/edit/ is preappended to the url in the edit case?
Any idea how to fix it?

I'll post code if it's useful, but thought this was probably something I don't understand about urls and routing.

Thanks

Here is the javascript

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("ProfessionTypeList", function (data) {
        var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
        $.each(data, function (i, professionType) {
            items += "<option value='" + professionType.Value + "'>" + professionType.Text + "</option>";
    });
    $("#ProfessionTypeId").html(items);
   })
});
```

Comment: Yes we need to see the code before we can find a solution.

Comment: It depends on how you are creating your URL. Are you using `@Url.Action`? or are you simply hard coding the URL. Looks to me as if it is the second case

Comment: I've tried @Ur.Action, but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line

```
$.getJSON("ProfessionTypeList",
```

will generate the URL of the form

```
http://domain.com/Controller/ActionName/ProfessionTypeList
```

i.e. it will append `ProfessionTypeList` at the end of the URL.

You should try to make explicit URL will complete path. 
In `CSHTML` file, you can do so by using `@Url.Action("ProfessionTypeList")`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Comet!

Here's some details of what I did in case it helps someone else.  I'm sure there's a cleaner way that doesn't use hidden fields.  Not sure if it matters though.

I created hidden fields with the urls as values.

```
    @Html.Hidden("ProfessionTypeListUrl",@Url.Action("ProfessionTypeList", "IsolatedPersonDetailAtEvent"), new { id = "ProfessionTypeListUrl" })
    @Html.Hidden("ProfessionSubTypeListUrl",@Url.Action("ProfessionSubTypeList", "IsolatedPersonDetailAtEvent"), new { id = "ProfessionSubTypeListUrl" })
```

Then I looked them up in my js.

```
  $(function () {

        var actionUrl = $("#ProfessionTypeListUrl").attr('value');

        $.getJSON(actionUrl, function (data) {
            var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
            $.each(data, function (i, professionType) {
                items += "<option value='" + professionType.Value + "'>" + professionType.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#ProfessionTypeId").html(items);
        })
    });


    $("#ProfessionTypeId").change(function ()
    {
        **var actionUrl = $("#ProfessionSubTypeListUrl").attr('value');**


        $.getJSON(actionUrl+"/" + $("#ProfessionTypeId > option:selected").attr("value"), function (data) {
            var items = "<option>---------------------</option>";
            $.each(data, function (i, subType) {
                items += "<option value='" + subType.Value + "'>" + subType.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#ProfessionSubTypeId").html(items);
        });
    });
</script>
```